# Python to convert CSV file to different output

Tags: pandas, csv

I have 2 CSV files like so:

**sheet1.csv  only contains headers**

```
Account_1 Amount_1 Currency_1 Country_1 Date_1
```

**sheet2.csv contains headers and data**

```
Account Currency    Amount    Date         Country
1        GBP         117.89   20/02/2021   UK
2        GBP         129.39   15/02/2021   UK
```

How can I use pandas to map the data from sheet2 to sheet1 as I want the data to have the new column names in the same exact order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First arrange the columns on sheet2 by order as sheet1

```
sheet2 = sheet2[["Account", "Amount", "Currency", "Country", "Date"]]
```

This will rearrange sheet2 columns and then

```
sheet2.columns = sheet1.columns
```

Final output of `sheet2.head()` will be

```
Account_1 Amount_1 Currency_1 Country_1 Date_1 
1         117.89   GBP        UK        20/02/2021
2         129.39   GBP        UK        15/02/2021
```

Comment: If you want to drop country field then don't put country name when arranging columns. for ex: `sheet2 = sheet2[["Account", "Amount", "Currency", "Date"]]` and if you want to make an excel file then you can use `sheet2.to_excel('sheet2.xlsx')`